# Rewrite Rules for specific pages to prevent specific culture

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have written a rewrite rule in my web.config file for a specific page and I want redirect it from Arabic culture 'ar' to English 'en' with parameter url.

My current rule is

```
<rule name="Home page with parameter" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^/ar/TestPage.aspx?id=10" />
<action type="Redirect" url="/en/TestPage.aspx?id={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

But its not working. Any other way can i achieved this ? Only this (TestPage.aspx) will be redirect. For other pages no need. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule will redirect:

`/ar/TestPage.aspx` to `/en/TestPage.aspx`

`/ar/TestPage.aspx?abc` to `/en/TestPage.aspx?abc`

`/ar/TestPage.aspx?id=10` to `/en/TestPage.aspx?id=10`

```
<rule name="Home page with parameter" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^ar(/TestPage.aspx)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/en{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

If you want to redirect only if query string has parameter `id`, then you need to modify rule like that:

```
<rule name="Home page with parameter" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^ar(/TestPage.aspx)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="id=" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="/en{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: your first rule is not working. TestPage.aspx sometime could have parameter sometime not. 
<rule name="Home page with parameter" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^ar(/TestPage.aspx)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/en{R:1}" />
</rule>

Comment: I just checked my rule again and it's working for `/ar/TestPage.aspx`. I received redirect to `/en/TestPage.aspx`

Comment: Do you have other redirect rules in your config? Which placed before "Home page with parameter" rule

Comment: I have only 2 rules 
  <rewrite>
      <rules>        
          <rule name="Home page with parameter" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^ar(/Home.aspx)" />
              <action type="Redirect" url="/en{R:1}" />
          </rule>                 
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

Comment: <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>

Comment: I am testing locally http://localhost:11006/ar/TestPage.aspx & comment out "Redirect to HTTPS" Only 1 rule i am using on local pc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152605/discussion-between-victor-leontyev-and-liton).

Comment: <rule name="Home page with parameter" stopProcessing="true"> 
<match url="^ar(/BackOffice/MyGifts.aspx$)" /> 
<action type="Redirect" url="/en/BackOffice{R:1}" /> 
</rule> 
I'm using this rule but problem is ,
/ar/BackOffice/MyGifts.aspx?Id=10 redirecting to ,
/en/BackOffice/BackOffice/MyGifts.aspx?Id=10 ,
"/BackOffice" is coming 2 times